# Automator - Set Selected Folder Path as Variable

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, automator

I'm trying to setup an Automator service that would download a list of URLs to the currently selected folder, or wherever the service was ran from. The only problem is I don't see how I would go about setting the currently selected folder as a path to download the files to. I'm thinking of something like this:

[image: Screenshot of my Automator idea]

**Note: Just realized I had service receives selected as "TEXT in ANY APPLICATION" in my screenshot. This will be "FOLDERS in FINDER" when I hopefully get this figured out!**

Where **currentFolder** currently selected folder, or wherever the service was ran from. As far as I can tell, I would just need to somehow set the currently selected folder as a variable like currentFolder, then set the Download URLs location to that variable? Let me know if I need to explain anything further!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took a slightly different route, and just setup a shell script. Apparently **cd "$@";** will get the current directory. [View a picture of my new automator service workflow.](https://i.imgur.com/VkEye5S.jpg)

Basically, I created a new service in Automator, then set Service Receives Selected to "files or folders" in "Finder", and added a "Run Shell Script" to the workflow. I set Shell to "/bin/bash", and Pass Input to "as arguments", then placed the following in the script editor.

```
cd "$@";
curl -O http://www.example.com/file1.zip
curl -O http://www.example.com/file2.zip
curl -O http://www.example.com/file3.zip
unzip \*.zip
rm *.zip
```

Now I can right click on any folder, and download my list of files.

Comment: This will only work if you select *one* folder. `$@` expands to all arguments passed to the script, so if you select multiple folders or even files, `cd` doesn't know what to do with them. I'll try and see if I can come up with an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a env to current dir with this command:

```
$currentDir=$PWD
```

you can then export it

```
$export currentDir
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer sajjadG! I'm not very familiar with the Automator program, so I'm sorry beforehand if this should be pretty obvious, but would I place the commands you've listed in as an AppleScript or a Shell Script?

Also, in what order would I place these? I would assume `$currentDir=$PWD` at the very start, and `$export currentDir` just before setting the download location?

Comment: @KellyLawrence sorry but I am not familiar with automator but wikipedia says that both of them will work. automaro can use both unix command line scripts (which is what I posted) and AppleScripts.

Comment: No worries @sajjadG! I appreciate you taking the time to provide an answer. As you can see in my answer below, I took a slightly different approach after doing some more research, but the end goal was achieved, regardless!